# How do I stream updates from BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

As data arrives in my BigQuery, I want to send some of it to another database--a datamart or an operational database that serves real-time dashboards.

How do I do this? Polling the enormous BQ table is too expensive and slow, and I want updates to be frequent--close to real-time.

Strangely, I find little info about streaming *from* BigQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Polling the enormous BQ table is too expensive and slow

Make sure to partition your data by day, and if you have too much data, cluster it by hour.

There isn't a natural way to stream data out of BigQuery as it arrives, but if you partition and cluster your data appropriately, then scans will be way less costly than doing it from a naive table.

For realtime: Would it be an option to split data to BigQuery and other tools from the pipeline, instead of after it being stored in BQ?

---

To the comment

> "I would rather not alter each of clients to write to two targets, BQ plus PubSub"

Have each client write only to Pub/Sub. Then click-to-deploy a pipeline that writes to BigQuery from Pub/Sub - for the most reliable pipeline. Then other consumers can subscribe to the same Pub/Sub topic that feeds BigQuery.

Comment: > "Make sure to partition your data by day, and if you have too much data, cluster it by hour."

That makes it difficult to run full analytics queries across multiple tables. Is there a way to write to both the partitioned and full tables as the data arrives --again, a type of event/trigger?

Comment: >"option to split data to BigQuery and other tools from the pipeline" 

I would rather not alter each of clients to write to two targets, BQ plus PubSub.

Comment: Oh cool. I updated my answer (clients shouldn't write to BigQuery, but to Pub/Sub)